# A practice(?) I have ... since I was an undergraduate student

Tags: word-request, verbs, nouns

I wonder what verbs can be used before the noun "practice". I want to say something like

> I am currently organizing a student study group. Organizing study groups a practice I have ____ since I was an undergraduate student.

What verb can I use in _____?(done, conducted?) Is it better if I change "practice" to something else?

Comment: What meaning do you intend for *practice*? What you mean in the second sentence is unclear. Also, *study groups*, not *studies groups*.

Comment: Thanks! I meant "I have been organizing study groups since I was an undergraduate student" in the second sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently organizing a student study group. Organizing study groups a practice I have ____ since I was an undergraduate student.

**I have been organizing them since I was an undergraduate student.**
That is the simplest way to say it.

Alternatively: **Organizing study groups is an activity I have been pursuing since I was an undergraduate**.

To pursue an activity=to do something for some period of time

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep that sentence structure the best option would be:

> Organizing study groups **is** a practice I have **had** since I was an undergraduate student.

You should consider changing it to:

> Organizing study groups has been my practice since I was an undergraduate student.